# Adding a prefix to the key of an object in axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, axios, prefix

I have the object

```
data = {
    others: [
        {
            code: "A", label: "0-A"
        },
        {
            code: "B", label: "0-B"
        },
        ...,
        {
            code: "N", label: "0-N"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I need to add the `other_` prefix to `code` value(example, `other_N`) before sending it to the axios query:

```
await axios.post(`${URL}`, { data })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```js
let data = {
  others: [{
      code: "A",
      label: "0-A"
    },
    {
      code: "B",
      label: "0-B"
    },
    {
      code: "N",
      label: "0-N"
    }
  ]
};

let modifiedData = data.others.map(x => {
  x.code = `other_${x.code}`;
  return x;
})

console.log(modifiedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to manipulate the data object

```js
data.others.map(x => { return { other_code: x.code, label: x.label }})
```